# 'usecols' not working while writing to csv

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have tow csv files File1 and File2. I am basically modifying File2 to match the columns in File1. In the final step i need to truncate the modified File2 to have only the first 50 columns. I wrote this program.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/merged_34_final_ordered.csv', dtype = 'unicode')
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/merged_52_raw_ip_2016_06_30.csv', dtype = 'unicode')
df3 = df2.T.reindex(df1.columns).T
df3['idSite'] = pd.Series([52 for x in range(len(df3.index))], index=df3.index)
df3.to_csv('C:/Users/merged_52_raw_ip_2016_06_30_reordered.csv',usecols = list(range(50)),index=False)
```

This does not seem to work as it does not truncate the file. It works only if we add it during the read_csv.

Answer (score 4):

The correct argument for [`DataFrame.to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) is `columns`, not `usecols` — the latter is for [`pd.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). However, as @ptrj points out, `to_csv()` expect column names. You can select the first 50 columns and call `to_csv()` on them,

```
df.iloc[:,:50].to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

or use @ptrj's approach to get the names of the first 50 columns.

Comment: Apparently that does not take index i guess. Because i got the error `KeyError: 'None of [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]] are in the [columns]'`

Comment: In Python 2, `range(50)` is already a list, so `list(range(50))` is a list containing a list containing 50 elements. Do `columns=range(50))` instead of `columns=list(range(50)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your code can be simplified:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(...)
df2 = pd.read_csv(...)

df3 = df2.reindex(columns=df1.columns)
df3['idSite'] = 52

# names of the first 50 cols:
cols = df3.columns[:50]
df3.to_csv('filename', columns=cols, index=False)
```

You are getting the error because `to_csv` expects column names.